# Add background color dynamically to even row groups

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have code as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange" : false,
      "paging": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets"  : 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
      }],
      "order": []
    });
    
    $('#example th').click(function(e) {
      let clicked_col_class = $(this).attr('class');
        if(clicked_col_class.includes('office')){
          $('#example tbody tr.xbg-dark-grey').removeClass('xbg-dark-grey').addClass('bg-dark-grey');
        }else{
          $('#example tbody tr.bg-dark-grey').removeClass('bg-dark-grey').addClass('xbg-dark-grey');
        }
    });
} );
```

```css
.bg-dark-grey{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05) !important;
}
.bg-white{
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="example" class="xdisplay" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="no-sort">Name</th>
                <th class="no-sort">Position</th>
                <th class="office">Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th class="no-sort">Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2011/04/25</td>
              <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
              <td>Support Lead</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>2013/03/03</td>
              <td>$342,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>2012/03/29</td>
              <td>$433,060</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Sonya Frost</td>
              <td>Software Engineer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>23</td>
              <td>2008/12/13</td>
              <td>$103,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
              <td>Ashton Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
              <td>2009/01/12</td>
              <td>$86,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
              <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
              <td>Sales Assistant</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>59</td>
              <td>2012/08/06</td>
              <td>$137,500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Garrett Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
              <td>2011/07/25</td>
              <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Airi Satou</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008/11/28</td>
              <td>$162,700</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>55</td>
              <td>2010/10/14</td>
              <td>$327,900</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
              <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2012/12/02</td>
              <td>$372,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
              <td>Paul Byrd</td>
              <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>64</td>
              <td>2010/06/09</td>
              <td>$725,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
              <td>Gloria Little</td>
              <td>Systems Administrator</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>59</td>
              <td>2009/04/10</td>
              <td>$237,500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Jena Gaines</td>
              <td>Office Manager</td>
              <td>London</td>
              <td>30</td>
              <td>2008/12/19</td>
              <td>$90,560</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
              <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
              <td>London</td>
              <td>43</td>
              <td>2012/12/18</td>
              <td>$313,500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
              <td>Regional Director</td>
              <td>London</td>
              <td>19</td>
              <td>2010/03/17</td>
              <td>$385,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Michael Silva</td>
              <td>Marketing Designer</td>
              <td>London</td>
              <td>66</td>
              <td>2012/11/27</td>
              <td>$198,500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-white">
              <td>Bradley Greer</td>
              <td>Software Engineer</td>
              <td>London</td>
              <td>41</td>
              <td>2012/10/13</td>
              <td>$132,000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Here, I have used `tr class` `bg-white` and `bg-dark-grey` manually. However, in real case scenario there is a simple logic on php. It is something like

```
$bg_class = '';
foreach($data as $dv){
    if($old_office != $dv->office){
        if($bg_class == 'bg-white'){
            $bg_class = 'bg-dark-grey';
        }else{
            $bg_class = 'bg-white';
        }
        $old_office = $dv->office;
    }
}
```

However, you can ignore this php logic just remember that initially on even row group of office there will be `background: dark-grey`. On this initial scenario: `San Francisco and New York` will have a background as they are even row (office) group.

```
Edinburgh
San Francisco //even (bg-grey)
Tokyo
New York //even (bg-grey)
London
```

For ordering other than the `office` column none of the rows will the background and I have already implemented logic for that one.
But, whenever I tried sorting with the office column. Let's consider `sorting_asc` condition:

```
Edinburgh
London
New York //(bg-grey)
San Francisco //(bg-grey)
Tokyo
```

In this case scenario, wrong row groups are having a background. As it is a client side datatable, php logic won't be executing again. So, I need some help so that I could add bacground to correct group whenever it is sorted based on office column. So my desired result are:

##For sorting_asc (office column)

```
Edinburgh
Edinburgh
Edinburgh
Edinburgh
London //desired-grey-row
London //desired-grey-row
London //desired-grey-row
London //desired-grey-row
London //desired-grey-row
New York 
New York 
New York 
San Francisco //desired-grey-row
San Francisco //desired-grey-row
Tokyo
Tokyo
Tokyo
```

##For sorting_desc (office column) (consider group not single row)

```
Tokyo
San Francisco //desired-grey-row
New York 
London //desired-grey-row
Edinburgh
```

i.e every even group row needs to have a grey background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - this is a javascript way to highlight alternating office rows:

```js
function highlightRows() {
  let t = document.getElementById("example");
  let tbody = t.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  let lastoffice = "";
  let lastclass = "bg-dark-grey";
  for (let r = 0; r < tbody.rows.length; r++) {
    let thisrow = tbody.rows[r];
    let thisoffice = thisrow.cells[2].innerHTML;
    if (thisoffice != lastoffice) {
      lastclass = (lastclass == "bg-dark-grey")? "bg-white": "bg-dark-grey";
      lastoffice = thisoffice;
      thisrow.className = lastclass;
    } else {
      thisrow.className = lastclass;
    }
  
  }
}

// for testing purposes only
window.onload = highlightRows;
```

```css
.bg-dark-grey{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05) !important;
}
.bg-white{
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="example" class="xdisplay" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="no-sort">Name</th>
          <th class="no-sort">Position</th>
          <th class="office">Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th class="no-sort">Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-dark-grey">
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-white">
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can call this from "document ready" function directly (I've used `window.onload` to achieve the same thing, for testing purposes only though).  Your existing code removes the grey backgrounds if you sort by age or salary so that part is ok, but you can then call this function again if you are sorting by office instead.

I'm sure that there's a php or jquery method as well, but I tend to use vanilla javascript.

Comment: Could you provide options for sorting for office and age and salary column as in provided code?

Comment: You already have that in your own code.  This is just a new function that you can call in your "document ready" code and if the sorting is done by office.  There's no need to do an entire copy of your code as you only need to copy/paste the "highlightRows" function into your own code and call it where necessary.

Comment: It does run.  You are not seeing anything change in the table because you have not included the right css classes - you need to have `bg-dark-grey` and `bg-white` as these are the styles used on the highlighting.  Change what you have by removing the 'x' or add in the actual styles and you will see it work ok.

Comment: it does not seems working https://jsfiddle.net/9sc1p2ta/1/, obviously at initial load its working but i don't think its because your function but because of the pre added class bg-white and bg-dark-grey on tr

Comment: Those two classes are in the css part of your Question, so I would have expected them to be there in the tests as well?

Comment: could you check why it's not adding background correctly when I tried to sort by office in the provided link? https://jsfiddle.net/9sc1p2ta/1/

Comment: Try it now [https://jsfiddle.net/3gfvyr0o/](https://jsfiddle.net/3gfvyr0o/)

Comment: this is what I wanted. Actually, you could copy those jsfiddle code snippet to the code block in stackoverflow, that suits more than the current one.

Comment: I've updated my own Answer with the minor changes.  I won't update the Question's content as that is your code.